# How to compile libcouchbase on mac

Tags: couchbase

Hello i'm trying to compile libcouchbase c library https://github.com/couchbase/libcouchbase
so i can use it to call couchbase.so on php.ini,
 means to use couchbase for php on nginx 
i'm getting the following error when i compile.

`fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
configure.ac:22: error: AC_INIT should be called with package and version arguments
/opt/local/share/aclocal-1.11/init.m4:26: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE is expanded from...
configure.ac:22: the top level
autom4te: /opt/local/bin/gm4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: /opt/local/bin/autom4te failed with exit status: 1
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1`

please any help

Comment: My guess here is that you don't have git install on you machine. Can you try installing git and compiling again.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you to track down your compiling issue, but you don't have to compile it for yourself just to get it up and running. Couchbase officially provides binaries for OSX here: http://www.couchbase.com/develop/php/current